# Free strings and buffers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arraybuffer

I know that JS engine automatically delete from memory "unused" objects. So if we have some enormous object and want to free memory we have to do something like this:

```
largeObject = null
```

And if we haven't any other links to our object it will be removed by engine soon. It's clear. But what if we have enormous string. For example we have read it from file:

```
largeString = fs.readFileSync('bigdata.txt', 'utf8')
```

Can we tell engine that we will not use this string?

```
largeString = null
```

It's work only for objects, but string is a primitive type.

Also will it work with buffers:

```
let largeData = rs.readFileSync('bigdata')
/* Some code */
largeData = null
```

JS engine should understand that we will not use this buffer and free it. But `Buffer` is inherited from `Int8Array` and the last is just view for some `ArrayBuffer`. Which is accessable by `largeData.buffer`. Of course after `largeData = null` we lose access to this ArrayBuffer and so memory should be free in some time. Am I right in this purpose?

I know, that JS is not language about memory manipulations, but in my opinion very important to understand how engine frees memory to minimize risk of the memory lick.

Answer (score 1):

> But what if we have enormous string.

Strings are primitive values just like numbers. You can't have references to strings. However, strings can be deallocated when they are not reachable.

> JS engine should understand that we will not use this buffer and free it. But `Buffer` is inherited from `Int8Array` and the last is just view for some `ArrayBuffer`. Which is accessable by `largeData.buffer`. Of course after `largeData = null` we lose access to this `ArrayBuffer` and so memory should be free in some time. Am I right in this purpose?

You are right. Because the only way to access the buffer is through `largeData.buffer`, if there are no references to `largeData`, the buffer can also be deallocated.

---

It's worth noting that the EcmaScript Specification doesn't specify when/how garbage collection happens. In fact, an engine that never collects garbage may be completely spec-compliant. In practice, however, most engines do that, to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: So if we have enormous string in variable `str` after `str = null` it we be removed from memory like object?

Comment: @SergeiMartianov Yes

Comment: But there is a string interning is JS, so every string will be added to pool and will stored there forever. Or not? Or if engine had had problems with memory it would remove unused strings from pool?

Comment: @SergeiMartianov The strings are freed if there is no way to access them.

Comment: Exectly like objects? So string is primitive type just for convenience (e.g.value assignment instead of reference assignment)?

Comment: @SergeiMartianov Basically, yes.